# Async method in web-app does not complete if it is not awaited - execution just steps back out into the controller. Why?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a simple web app, built with .NET Core (3.1) MVC and EF Core 5, containing a PersonController and a PersonService. (The project was provided by a teacher in my educational program, and he doesn't understand why the problem occurs either.) I work with VS2019.

The PersonController contains a constructor initializing a PersonService, and a delete-method:

```
public PersonController(IPersonService personService)
{
    _PersonService = personService;
}

[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
    _ = _PersonService.DeleteAsync(id);

    TempData["Message"] = "successfully deleted";

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

The PersonService contains a DbContext and the DeleteAsync() method:

```
private readonly MyContext _context;

public async Task DeleteAsync(int? id)
{
    Person person = await _context.People.FindAsync(id);
    _context.Remove(person);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

The problem:

The person is not removed from the database. When debugging, `_PersonService.DeleteAsync(id)` is called, the method executes until _context.Remove(person) but `await _context.SaveChangesAsync()` never gets executed. The execution returns to the calling method, and the TempData message shows up. The person-entry is not deleted from the database. This is the first time I've seen Visual Studio step out of a method before completion.

I can resolve this problem when I replace the Discard `_ =` with `await`. In this case, the code executes as expected -- but I've read that "fire and forget" can be totally fine under the right circumstances.

I've also read that controllers are discarded after each request - but when the method in the PersonService stops executing, the debugger is still in the controller (at the TempData), so it seems that this can't be the reason.

Can someone explain what's causing the method to stop executing before it's done? Or alternatively, maybe you could tell me how I can find out what's happening in the background by using some feature of the debugger I'm unaware of, or something like that?

Comment: Check your DI configuration. Almost certainly `IPersonService` has been registered with a lifetime tied to the request, so you trying to continue using it after the request is over is very much not going to be allowed for a "fire and forget" scenario.

Comment: Could you tell me how to check the DI configuration? Also, my confusion comes from the task being "interrupted" before the SaveChangesAsync() call, returning execution to the controller. From what I've read, problems can arise because controllers are discarded after requests, but the controller is still executing when the Task stops executing.

Comment: DI configuration is in your startup/program.cs file. Where you should have written stuff like `services.AddScoped<Iterface, Implentation>()`

Comment: @Scryper Ah, I didn't know that this was the DI configuration. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're not awaiting the task so it won't necessarily complete before the enclosing method does. The `SaveChangesAsync()` task doesn't complete as it would block the current thread, so the enclosing method needs suspending for `SaveChangesAsync()` to complete before it ends.

Consider replacing

```
 _ = _PersonService.DeleteAsync(id);
```

with

```
await _PersonService.DeleteAsync(id).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: Yes, I said that await resolves the problem. I would nonetheless like to understand why the task doesn't complete.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the method call doesn't get executed is that you are using "fire and forget" by using the discard _ = instead of await. This means that the method will execute in the background without waiting for it to complete.

Since the DeleteAsync() method is not awaited, the controller method will return a response to the client before the database operation is completed. This may cause the connection to the database to be closed before the operation is finished.

It's important to use await on method's if you want them to finish.

Comment: As stated in the question, I'm aware that the controller is discarded after a request. But when debugging, the task seems to be "interrupted" before SaveChangesAsync(), and the execution returns to the controller, which still exists at that point. That's where my confusion arises. I've also said that "await" resolves the problem - I'd nonetheless like to understand why the problem occurs without "await".

Comment: The connection to the database might already be closed. That's why SaveChangesAsync() might not get executed.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how I could check this?

Comment: I never did. but you if you are interested you could create a new question. Just a quick research on my side you could try:    if (!_context.Database.CanConnect())
                throw new Exception("Database connection is closed.");

Answer (score 0):

Other people answered what should be the correct way to handle this and that is to **await** your async methods.

However, i believe what you are asking is why the person is not **eventually deleted**.

The problem is not that the `DeleteAsync()` task in not completed, but rather that when the controller returns *(while the task runs in the background probably still in the `FindAsync()` line)* the **service provider scope** for this request is disposed/destroyed. When the task continues from the `FindAsync()`, deletes record *(in memory)* and tries to `SaveAsync()` it will result in an exception *(since dbcontext is disposed)* that will not be observed since no one is awaiting/observing the task.

Comment: I'm aware that awaiting resolves the problem. My confusion comes from the fact that when the execution leaves the DeleteAsync() method, it returns to the controller, which has not returned at this point. The task executes until _context.Remove(person); and then execution continues in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

In your main method, you can configure your  `IPersonService` as a singleton, because currently I believe `IPersonService` is configured as `Scoped` . By current configuration as Scoped, the `IPersonService` will be destroyed when the requested has been completed to the user, this the `DeleteAsync` is not properly completed. By implementing Singleton instead of Scope, the requested will continue event though the request already completed. Noted that this is just for academic purposes, and the best practices is still to use await instead of fire and forget